# Force query to match more than one attribute

Tags: algolia

I have an index that includes these attributes: Name, Address, City, State, Zip

I want to do a `allOptional` search but I don't want city, state, or zip to match without name or address also matching. So a search query of `McDonalds` would match all McDonalds in every city/state, `McDonalds Chicago` would return all McDonalds in Chicago and `McDonalds 60007` would return all McDonalds in the zip code 60007.

But a search query of `Chicago` or `Chicago IL` would return 0 results.

I've been reading the filters and facets documentation and I think this should be possible with a filter but I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by post processing results after you have received them, before rendering them.

You can use the `_highlightResult` data in the hits response to filter out hits in which the query isn't matched in certain attributes.

For instance to remove hits where the query isn't matched in either the `name` or `address` attribute:

```
var displayedResults = response.hits.filter(hit => {
    return hit._highlightResult.name.matchLevel !== 'none' || hit._highlightResult.address.matchLevel !== 'none';
});
```

Comment: hmmm, hadn't thought of that. Wouldn't that throw off the number of results returned though? I suppose I could ask for more than I actually want and then filter the results down.

Comment: you're right, it would make the results count inaccurate, so depending on your use-case this might not be acceptable